# Single Property bound to multiple controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

I have a single property that consists of three letters and two numbers, such as "ABC 12". The requirements for my project ask that the UI divide this into a ComboBox for the three letter combinations and a TextBox for the numerical. I can do this pretty easily using a converters to  parse out the part of the string that I need.

My question is whether there is a way to implement the "ConvertBack" logic in my converter such that I can reset the property based upon the values in the two different controls.

My xaml:

```
<ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding EditMode}" ItemsSource="{Binding AbbrevsList}"      
          DisplayMemberPath="SelectedAbbrev" SelectedValuePath="Abbrev" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Row.Code, Converter=CodeAlphaConverter, 
                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox TextAlignment="Left">
     <TextBox.Text>
          <Binding Path="Row.Code" Converter="CodeNumericConverter" 
                   UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
          </Binding>
      </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not having two fields (string and number) which are classically bind and then a property which combined both ?

Comment: The only reason I have avoided doing that is because the alphanumeric code is saved as a single string in my data source.

Comment: IMHO, it's sounds more like a design issue then i mean, the datasource has not to be the same object a gui ones. what do you think ?

Comment: I agree with ykatchou. That'll be the cleanest way to do it. And you can load/save the combined property from/into the datasource without an issue.

Comment: Am i missing something? The convertback method for the Converter allows the reverse, so have you tried it? If so, what are the errors?

Comment: The pieces that I need to convert back are in two separate controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WPF does not allow you to bind converter parameters, you may have to switch your approach.  Instead of using converters, other answers on SO point to changing your View Model to have the logic built into two properties and binding to those or, instead of passing in the individual value to the converter, you pass in the entire object.